# CMake Error Compiler Not Working

Tags: c++

I've been tryin to build the vxl libary with CMaker for several hours, but have been encountering error after error...

The last one... (I've checked and I don't have sh.exe on my path):

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_ff6a8\fast"
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/vxl-root/obj-e/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_ff6a8\fast"

  The system cannot find the file specified

  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
  "cmTC_ff6a8\fast"





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (PROJECT)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/vxl-root/obj-e/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/vxl-root/obj-e/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

[image]

Comment: what C++ compiler do you have, and what path to it?

Comment: MinGW, with paths C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe and C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe

Comment: have you Visual Studio? you need `gnu make` or `nmake` from VS to build stuff

Comment: Let me install VS... :)

Comment: Hm, VS for nmake not needed (I mean VS too big to install it just to use nmake), you can install gnu make for win32: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm it is much better 3MB vs N GB of VS

Comment: Still not working @user1034749, attaching a screenshot to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94245/discussion-between-mrd-and-user1034749).

Comment: First you need nmake or make in your PATH (may require reboot of windows), second cmake cache results, so after cmake failed and you something change you need remove CMakeCache.txt from build directory.

Comment: @fghj `cmake`, `clang-cl`, `make` all in path; damn shit from microsoft just won't ever work!